# How to find the closest node to connect to mainnet in my dapp?

Tags: mainnet, eosjs

In our dapp, we would like to offer the user to choose from a list of different mainnet nodes, so that latency is low.

Ideally, from the list of BPs the user has voted for.

How to retrieve a list of mainnet nodes (in the web app)?

Comment: Did you have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know you want a web API for this but the simple thing to do would be to get cleos installed and call it from an AJAX endpoint to run:

```
cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io  system  listproducers
```

This returns the list of BPs with URLs and then you can just call any of these BP websites with /bp.json to retrieve the API endpoints for that BP.

PS: The cleos call itself require a BP (I used EOSNewYork as an example).

Comment: If you want to know which one is "closest", you can try pinging them to see which of the BPs respond the fastest.

Comment: Yes, I want a web API and a sever-less app.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an API that is automatically geo routed based on where you are requesting from (like EOSInfra)

```
curl -si https://public.eosinfra.io/v1/chain/get_info
```

The API currently has 40ms latency from my location. Which is a reasonably good latency.