# How could I can select a good block producer

Tags: block-producer

Currently, when I develop my dApp, I select a BP to push my transaction to blockchain. But I am wondering, what's happen when thats BP to become a standby BP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any working nodeos endpoint will enable you to push a transaction to the blockchain. It doesn't matter if it is run by a BP in the Top 20 or not.

You can use the answer here, https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1221/3333, to get a list of nodeos endpoints that you could use. Just use whichever endpoint you find reliable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am wondering if I push my transaction to BP which is standby, so my transaction does not sign.

Comment: You don't push a transaction to a specific BP. You submit it to the network through the nodeos p2p plugin and it gets picked up by a BP through a queue.

Comment: Well I think the nodeos which I push my transaction to it. it will be valid it first before my transaction be broadcast to blockchain, it is right?

` BP through a queue.`

What is a queue? Each trusted BP will have a queue?